# A combinatorial enumeration problem on graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a complete graph of order $n$, we now delete $i$ edges from it, then how many complete subgraphs are there with order $m$ in the rest graph?

(You can assume $m\ll n$ and $i\ll m$ if necessary)

Indeed, the number of the subgraphs should not be a precise number since it depends on the way how we delete the edges, but I think the magnitude(i.e. the $\varepsilon$ when write the number as $n^\varepsilon$) is invariant.

Comment: It really depends on which edge you delete. So your problem is that when $i$ edges are chosen arbitrarily, compute the expectation of number of subgraph $K_m$?

Comment: @Golbez Yes, or to give a lower bound is also welcome, thanks.

Comment: To give yourself some calibration ideas, I suggest working out the answer when the $i$ edges share a common vertex, and again when the $i$ edges use $2i$ distinct vertices.

Comment: Here is a solution to calculate an "average" size: let us consider the tuples $(E,K)$ where $E$ are the deleted edges and $K$ denote the complete subgraph such that $K$ and $E$ disjoined, fix a subgraph $K_m$ one can easily knows that the number of $K$s is $\binom{i}{n^2-m^2}$, so the number of such tuples is $\binom{m}{n}\binom{i}{n^2-m^2}$, hence the "average" $K$ for each $E$ is $\frac{\binom{m}{n}\binom{i}{n^2-m^2}}{\binom{i}{n^2}}$

Comment: this question seems a little trivial, I somewhat think too complicate before, thanks to all the guys who comment to my question.